# Post failing in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

This is the function I'm using to POST data,

```
export function postData(url, senderId, receiverId, mediaId){
  return fetch(url, { headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
                      credentials: 'include',
                      mode: 'no-cors',
                      method: 'POST',
                      body: JSON.stringify({"senderId": senderId, "receiverId": receiverId, "mediaId": mediaId})
  })
    .then((response) => { console.log('Status: ', response.status);})
    .catch((error) =>{ console.log("Request failed: ", error) ;

    });

}
```

This is the component that makes the POST

```
class HomePage extends React.Component{
......
 handleSubmit(data){
   ......
    postData(post_url, this.state.user.yguid, this.state.receiverId, this.state.mediaId);

  }

render(){
    return(
        <div className="col-md-2 left-pane">
          <Sidebar handleSubmit= {this.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>

    );
  }

}
```

This is the Server endpoint handling the POST

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/send/",
                    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Void> send(@RequestBody Message message) {

        try {
            controller.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I continue to get the following error message,

```
POST http://localhost:9000/myserver/send/ 415 ()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The server is erroring. It's impossible to answer this question without knowing the code for the `/send` route. Look at your server logs to see if there's any helpful information.

Comment: The end point works fine and I've tested it on Postman.

Comment: @AndyRay I've updated the question with the server code.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but a 415 error is unsupported media type, likely cause your endpoint expects something other than `application/json`. It'll likely work in Postman because it's very good at supplying a lot of default headers.

Without the server code the best answer to your question is: it's failing because of missing headers. Which? We don't know.